# Disable a TListViewItem

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

Does anyone know if its possible to disable a single Item in a FireMonkey TListView?

Comment: Disable as in block user input for a particular item, I presume?

Comment: @JerryDodge yes exactly that

Comment: what if you check your item inside ItemClick or ItemClickEx event.. if match then  exit? (against AItem: TListViewItem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I'm programmatically building the listview, the item won't be included in the listview when certain events occur in my app, otherwise it will be included.

```
procedure Tform1.BuildListView;
var LItem : TListViewItem;
begin
  ListView1.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ListView1.ClearItems;

  if (SOMETHING HAPPENS) then
  begin
    LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
    LItem.Text := 'Item 1';
    LItem.Tag := 0;
  end;

  LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
  LItem.Text := 'Item 2';
  LItem.Tag := 1;

  LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
  LItem.Text := 'Item 3';
  LItem.Tag := 2;

  LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
  LItem.Text := 'Item 4';
  LItem.Tag := 3;

  finally
    ListView1.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```